# Xcode 10 archive build compile failure

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10

Building on devices and simulator works fine in Xcode 10 but an archive build in Xcode 10 hangs up at the same spot each time (cpu maxes out too), at the very end of "Compile Sources" but never goes to the next build phase. Of course, when I quit the build I get an uncategorized SwiftCodeGeneration warning (also using legacy build system also fails, also same happens before and after updating to swift 4.2). Anyone else running into this?

Another note, not using cocoapods, tried removing all my embedded frameworks and still had the same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

remove the armv7 from supported architecture works for me

Answer (score 0):

I found some answers to this problem.

1. I adjusted the level of optimization, this allowed me to get past the "compile sources" build phase (in particular "fastest and smallest" and "optimize for speed").
2. the compiling then got stuck on the "copy bundle resources" phase. making sure my project folder names matched the actual folder names and making sure all my resources were linked properly by deleting the reference to a few and re-entering them into the project I was able to successfully compile. Again this was a project that worked a couple days ago on Xcode 9. Hope this helps someone, cheers.